# Regex with double negative matches

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Given a series of strings:

- error.user
- success
- success.user
- success.admin

I want to write a regex that will match anything not starting with `error`, and that also doesn't have `.user` in it.  So for this list, `success` and `success.admin`

What I've got so far is: `/^((?!error)\w*)((?!\.*user)\w*)/`

The first part: `((?!error)\w*)` is working fine, and narrowing down the matches to just strings that start with `success`.  For some reason the second part: `((?!\.*user)\w*)` is doing precisely nothing.  I think the first part is matching too much.

I'm doing this in PHP/PCRE
Here's my regex101.com link: https://regex101.com/r/l2sZru/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your negative regex like this:

```
^(?!error|.*\.user)[\w.]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l2sZru/5)

Here `(?!error|.*\.user)` will assert failure if `error` is at the start OR if .user` is found anywhere in the input.

`(?!\.*user)` in your regex means assert failure when input has 0 or more DOTs followed by `user` at the start only.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: It is shorter to write `^(?!error|.*\.user)[\w.]+$`